# How to detect when Android phone is gone idle

Tags: android

I have service running in background whose job is to detect whenever phone is IDLE for more than certain time then show a popup message with an Image.

I could not find how do I detect that phone is in idle state now.

**UPDATE**

IDLEness is represented by following three scenarios

1) User inactivity

2) Screen goes off

3) sensors: gyroscope (x,y,z) and accelerometer remains 0 for a defined amount of time.

thanks

leo

Comment: What do you mean by "idle" in this context?

Comment: 1) User has not interacted with phone for certain time 2) Phone screen goes off when not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) User has not interacted with phone for certain time

There is no means for you to determine this.

> 2) Phone screen goes off when not used.

Listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts.

Comment: Could you please shed some light on 3rd case as well?

Comment: @leo: since they are almost never zero, that's not a scenario you can do.